# Completion of local ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Suppose we have a variety $X$ over an algebraically closed char 0 field $K$, and a point $p\in X$. If the completion of the local ring of $X$ at $p$ is isomorphic to $K[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]]/(f)$ for some polynomial $f$, what does this mean for the geometry of $X$ at $p$? Does there exist a nbhd $U$ of $p$ isomorphic to the affine variety defined by $f$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The completed local ring depends on information which is a lot more "local" than what the Zariski topology sees. For instance, for any smooth point $x$ in a variety $X$ with $\dim_x X = n$, the completed local ring will just be $K[[x_1,\cdots,x_n]]$. So the only chance of nontrivial $f$ would be if the point were singular. Even here, the completed local ring doesn't see much global information.

Consider the following two examples: $V(xy)$ and $V(y^2=x^2(x^2-1)(x-2))$ both as subschemes of $\Bbb A^2_K$. It can be computed that the completed local ring at the origin of both of these is $K[[x,y]]/(xy)$, but there's no isomorphism between any open sets of the two varieties - up to shrinking the open set in $V(xy)$ so that it is only contained in one of the irreducible components, this would correspond to a birational map between curves of different genus, which is clearly nonsense.

Comment: A complete regular local ring containing a field is isomorphic to $k[[x_1,\cdots,x_n]]$. This is a fundamental result from commutative algebra called Cohen's Structure Theorem, see for instance [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0323). The completion of a local ring of a smooth point in a $K$-variety for $K$ any field will be a complete regular local ring, and one may apply the result (note that the $k$ from $k[[x_1,\cdots,x_n]]$ need not be the same as the $K$ in this sentence).

Comment: Tks, I see now that if $\varprojlim A_p/p^r$ is larger than $k[[x_1,\ldots,x_n]]$ then some elements of $A_p$ are not approachable by a polynomial in $x_i$ and one them must be added to the generators of the maximal ideal so $A_p$ is not regular. Thus the main point is to show the maximal ideal is generated by $\dim(X)$ elements.