# Does the completions $\hat{\mathscr{O}}_P(X)\simeq \hat{\mathscr{O}}_Q(Y)$ could deduce local rings $\mathscr{O}_P(X)\simeq \mathscr{O}_Q(Y)$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-varieties, projective-varieties

In Hartshorne's algebraic geometry, he said the completion of local ring $\hat{\mathscr{O}}_P(X)$ takes much more 'local properties' than the local ring $\mathscr{O}_P(X)$. There are two natural questions:

1. If completions $\hat{\mathscr{O}}_P(X)\simeq\hat{\mathscr{O}}_Q(Y)$, then could we deduce $\mathscr{O}_P(X)\simeq\mathscr{O}_Q(Y)$?
2. The example of isomorphic local rings $\mathscr{O}_P(X)\simeq\mathscr{O}_Q(Y)$, but their completions $\hat{\mathscr{O}}_P(X)$, $\hat{\mathscr{O}}_Q(Y)$ are not isomorphic? (and this happened in which situtation? maybe related to singularity?)

In particular, if the second example could be figure out, then which means that the equivalent relation 'isomorphism' is not as stronger as I imaging before in category theory.

Comment: The completion is an isomorphism invariant of rings, but not a complete invariant, so (2) is false (i.e. there is no such example). (1) is also false: let $A$ denote the ring obtained by starting with a cubic with a node at $P = (0,0)$ (say $y^2 = x^3 - x^2$) and localizing its coordinate ring at $P$. Let $B$ denote the localization (again at the origin) of the coordinate ring of a line pair that cross at $P$, such as $x^2 - y^2 = 0$. Then $A \not\cong B$ (for instance, the cubic is irreducible but the line pair is not, so $A$ is an integral domain but $B$ is not), but $\hat A \cong \hat B$.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thank you for your answer! However, I feel more confused about Hartshorne's description 'the ordinary local ring $\mathscr{O}_P$ carries information about almost all of X, the completion $\hat{\mathscr{O}}_P$ carries much more local information', since according to your answer, it seems like ordinary local ring $\mathscr{O}_P$ contains its completion $\hat{\mathscr{O}}_P$'s information.

Comment: Potential duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3333356/completion-of-local-ring/3333360#3333360

Comment: @Frank does it help to rephrase Hartshorne as "the completion $\hat{\mathscr O}_P$ carries information which is far more local than $\mathscr O_P$? He's not saying that the completion contains "much more" information if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: I agree; my interpretation is that $\mathscr{O}_P$ contains a lot more global information, rather than $\hat{\mathscr{O}_P}$ containing more local information. This may have been a less confusing way to write what Hartshorne intended by the quoted passage. Completion should be somewhat of a 'forgetful' operation.

Comment: @TabesBridges Thank you so much for your explanation! I misunderstood the meaning of completion which Hartshorne would like to express.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll explain geometrically why the answer to your main question is a resounding no, using some basic facts about nonsingular projective curves.

Let $C$ and $C'$ be two nonsingular projective curves over $k$, and let $P, P' \in C, C'$ respectively. Then, the completions of the local rings are naturally isomorphic to $k[[t]]$ by the Cohen Structure Theorem. We will show that if $C$ and $C'$ are non-isomorphic, then there is no isomorphism between the respective local rings.

Indeed; an isomorphism of local $k$-algebras $\mathscr{O}_{C, P} \to \mathscr{O}_{C', P'}$ would (upon localizing) yield a $k$-isomorphism of function fields $K(C) \to K(C')$, which would imply that $C$ and $C'$ are birational, and hence isomorphic by Hartshorne's corollary I.6.12.

As for your second question, this cannot happen, since completion is functorial, and functors respect isomorphisms.

Edit: To elaborate on my comment, I'll give an example of how completions are useful in studying singularities. If we want to understand the singularities of curves, considering the local rings is not really sufficient. In particular, the local ring contains 'generic' data (like allowing us to recover the function field in the irreducible case) which yields a classification of singularities that is far too fine to be useful.

Completion gives a way to forget the generic data and understand only certain local properties. This gives way to a much better understanding of curve singularities. Many examples of this are in section I.5 of Hartshorne, and this is one of them, called a *node*.

[image]

This is the curve $\{(x + y)(x - y) = x^6 + y^6\}$, graphed in Desmos. Notice that the singularity looks a lot like the singularity obtained from the union of two lines $\{(x + y)(x - y) = 0\}$. These local rings at $(0,0)$ are clearly different since one is a domain and one is definitely not. However, you can show that both of these completions end up isomorphic to $k[[s, t]]/(st)$, so the completion is able to forget that one singularity comes from a reducible curve and the other does not.

Comment: Thank your for your perfect example! Actually, that perfectly explained the core question which confused me 'what are the uses of completions $\hat{\mathscr{O}}_P$, if they carry less information than original local rings $\mathscr{O}_P$'.

Comment: By the way, I assume that the reason for this matter is Zaraski topology is more coarse than general topology, so when we consider the local property at a point by using open neighborhood under Zaraski topology, it seems not really local.